# Does the engine compare the cost threshold for parallelism setting with each operator's cost?

Tags: sql-server, parallelism

SQL engine decides to run things in parallel threads when the cost exceeds the CTFP setting.

Say the CTFP value is 100.

Does the engine compare this threshold with each operator cost and then decide to run that respective operator in parallel threads?

Or is this check considering the combined operator costs? And then the engine decides to run the entire query in parallel?

Comment: What gives you the idea that parallelism is decided at operator level?

Comment: It's not decided that > CTFP it'll be parallel, it's still cost based. It just means it'll explore the space.

Comment: Is the CTFP compared with entire query cost. I'm asking because in the execution plan I have sometimes seen parallelism at various levels on the plan.